# It is safe to use OpenZeppelin v2.5 contracts (Solidity 0.5.0) in 2021?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin-contracts

I was checking some pretty old contract samples of OpenZeppelin v2.5, and they are in Solidity 0.5.0, and I am not sure if it is a safe version, or not.

If I extend these types of contracts, it makes me use Solidity 0.5.0 in my contracts, when we are in Solidity >0.8.

Should I keep my Solidity version updated to the 0.8, and only use compatible contracts, or should I forget about the Solidity versions?

Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any direct vulnerabilities in the 0.5.x versions. So you can just use them, if you wish.

The newer versions have more functionality and are maybe a bit safer to use - in the sense that they guide you to make better coding decisions. For example integer over/underflows are automatically checked in the newer versions, which makes your life easier.